# What is the equivalent of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES for CMake in Android?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I am linking statically multiple libraries in CMakeLists.txt. In Android.mk, LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES is used for that. What is the equivalent of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES for CMake in Android?

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libexample_static
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official [hello-libs sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs).

In the nutshell, you use

```
add_library(libexample_static)
…
add_library(mynativelib SHARED main_jni.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mynativelib
                      libexample_static
                      log)
```